# Windows Aero Window Preview custom buttons

Tags: windows, qt

Some applications on Windows 7 (Not sure about Vista) have custom buttons in their Aero window previews, below the actual window preview image, like so:

[image]

How would I go about implementing this in a Qt application, if that's at all possible? I'm also open to any solutions that might require me to toy around with the native WinAPI stuff.

Thanks for any ideas/pointers/responses y'alls may have.

Comment: Qt seems have no support for such feature. (except of some proprietary library, mentiond [there](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5694)) Study this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Windows just asks the window that is represented by the toolbar button to paint itself. And then shows that as the preview. Most likely the window associated with the taskbar button is not your app's main form window.

Comment: David Heffernan: I know the window preview itself is automatic, but I'm asking about those four buttons Skype adds below the preview.